# What is the difference of - $L^p$ spaces - defined using extended real line and real line functions?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, measurable-functions

This semester I am taking a course on Measure and Integration Theory. Our professor provided us with a script, written by him that covers the material of the course and contains the proofs. Nontheless there is another professor at my university that is a lot more rigurious and precise (which fits my needs more) and now I am parallel reading his book on Measure and Integration Theory as well. Up until the chapter about $L^p$ spaces everything was very similar.

But then my professor defined $L^p$ spaces using functions (equivalence classes of functions) that map from a set $\Omega$ to the extended real line $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$, where as the book I am also working with defined them as functions (again taking the equivalence class) that map from a set $\Omega$ to the real line $\mathbb{R}$.
Now my question is, is there an argument to define them in one of the above ways? Are the definitions related in some sense? And will the theory that comes out of the definitions be slightly different?

The book I mentioned above having the definitions with $\mathbb{R}$ can be found [here](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/measure.pdf) since the professor made the pdf publicly available on his homepage. And the definitions can be found on page 115.

This question was bugging me for so long. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: There isn't much difference at all since any $L^p$ function is finite a.e. and thus, up to redefining on a set of measure zero, we can take $L^p$ functions to be maps into $\mathbb R$. To illustrate the point $$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt x}, \,\,\, x \in [0,1]$$ is an $L^1$ map from $[0,1]$ to the extended real line. However, it is the same (in the $L^1$ sense) as the map $$g(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}, & 0 < x \le 1, \\ 0, & x = 0,\end{matrix} \right.$$ which is a map into $\mathbb R$.

Comment: So what you are saying is that, due to the equivalence relation of almost everywhere, the space $L^p$ regarding equivalenceclass of measurable maps to $\mathbb{R}$ is the same as the equivalenceclass $L^p$ of measurable maps to $\overline {\mathbb{R}}$?

Comment: Measurable and $p$-integrable maps: yes. Of course, if  you only require measurability, then maps to $\mathbb R$ and maps to $\overline{ \mathbb R}$ are not the same (even up too a.e. equivalence) since, for example, the constant map $f \equiv \infty$ is a measurable map to $\overline{\mathbb R}$ and there is no measurable map to $\mathbb R$ which is equivalent to it. However, since $L^p$ maps are finite almost everywhere for $1 \le p \le \infty$, when we discuss $L^p$ it is fine to only consider maps to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @User8128 Okay. Thanks a lot!!